# vertical align column with customized css on bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to use customized css on bootstrap 3, but failed. What I want is(on wide screen):

combo box located in vertical center on the left side.

The h3 Title located in center(This item is the highest).

The date mark located in bottom(This item is the shortest) on the right side.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js" />
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js" />
    <![endif]-->
    <style>
        .vcenter {
                vertical-align:middle
        }
        .vbottom {
                vertical-align:bottom
        }
    </style>
  </head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<form class="form-horizontal bg-info" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-4 vcenter">
      <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
        <select class="form-control">
          <option>a</option>
          <option>b</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h3><a href="#">Title</a></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 vbottom">
      <p class="text-right"><small>2014.09.03</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" />
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this you want? http://jsbin.com/reduvizavele/1/edit

Comment: @KheemaPandey No, just describe my requirement in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

for vertical align use `display: table-cell`

```
 .vcenter {
                vertical-align:middle;
                display:table-cell;

        }
```

Comment: This can not work. I'm using chromium, what's your test browser?

Answer (score 0):

Use inline `padding-top`, here is the [demo](http://jsbin.com/rekaxokucoli/1/edit?html,output)

1. left column: height 46px, add 5 px (=(56-46)/2)
2. middle column: height 56px
3. right column: height 30px, added 26 px(=56-30)

Cons:

1. Should manual calculate.
2. This method works on wide screen. It will get extra height on mobile phone.